# How to reassign values to existing columns of a data.table using lapply?

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I want to update NAs in numeric columns with median values for that column.

```
dt <- data.table(
  name = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
  sex = c("M","F",NA,"F","M"),
  age = c(1,2,3,NA,4),
  height = c(178.1, 162.1, NA, 169.5, 172.3)
)
```

Extract the numeric columns

```
num.cols <-  sapply(dt, is.numeric)
num.cols <- names(num.cols)[num.cols]
```

Check values

```
median(dt[,age], na.rm = T) # 2.5
median(dt[,height], na.rm = T) #170.9
```

Use lapply for each num.cols

```
dt[,lapply(.SD, function(value) 
ifelse(is.na(value), median(value, na.rm=TRUE), value)),
.SDcols = num.cols]
```

Question,  I cannot work out how to overwrite the vector with NA with the vector of imputed medians in data.table syntax ?

Comment: You're almost there, to overwrite the columns you want, just use `(num.cols) :=` right before your `lapply`

Comment: @MikeH. Thanks I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `na.aggregate` from `zoo` and specify the `FUN` as `median` to impute the missing values with `median` for the selected columns specified in `.SDcols` and assign (`:=`) the values to the concerned columns

```
library(zoo)
dt[, (num.cols) := na.aggregate(.SD, FUN = median),.SDcols = num.cols]
dt
#   name sex age height
#1:    A   M 1.0  178.1
#2:    B   F 2.0  162.1
#3:    C  NA 3.0  170.9
#4:    D   F 2.5  169.5
#5:    E   M 4.0  172.3
```